# Swift - How to set custom title in SKStoreReviewController?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

[image]
I wonder that if i can set custom title in SKStoreReviewController?
I read the apple document and search a lot in google
But I didn't find solution
What can I do if I want to implement the pop view like image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it with `SKStoreReviewController`. Some apps make a custom one but can't send the ratings to the App Store.

According to Apple Documentation:

> The SKStoreReviewController API lets you give users an easy way to
> provide feedback about your app. You can prompt for ratings up to
> three times in a 365-day period. Users will submit a rating through
> the standardized prompt, and can write and submit a review without
> leaving the app.

It means you can only show a standardized prompt. However, you can create a custom prompt and redirect the user to your app in the app store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's what I expected